# FormAuthentication persistant false but chrome remains logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, cookies, forms-authentication

I have tested on both firefox and internet explorer and both log out after the browser was closed but chrome remains logged in..

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Reallyy wierd, please help.

Comment: Fixed, Annoyingly enough, An updated version of chrome was set to keep chrome running in the background for performance. This was screwing me up.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, Annoyingly enough, An updated version of chrome was set to keep chrome running in the background for performance. This was screwing me up.